# Ebay Web Api Call

Tags: typescript, asp.net-web-api, ebay-api

I spent so much time trying to figure out the Ebay web api, and how to use it. I have integrated several different external web apis with not much difficulty, but that one is the most challenging one. They have tons of documentation, very good documentation, but lack practical examples.

Nevertheless, after some much time spent, I managed finally to make a first successful call to their service with Postman. This is the first time I have used such Postman format call, and will need help translating it into a real Angular 2 typescript web api Post call.

Here is the screenshot of the postman successful call setup:

[image]

[image]

So now, while finally this works as expected, how to translate it into angular 2 typescript Post web call?

Here is an example how successfully I make a web api call to one of my .net core web api:

[image]

Comment: Please replace the screenshot of code with actual text.

Answer (score 1):

**The reason why you are not able to get the same response is because you are not using the same request paths...**

Your screenshot is making a request with the path

```
[POST] http://{ip address}/ebay-categories/retrieve-and-store
```

However, the postman request is with the path

```
[POST] https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll
```

In addition, I don't see any request headers either. Such as, `Content-Type`, or `X-EBAY-API-SITEID`.

Comment: Thanks for response, as I have mentioned, I only provided a sample of the typescript code of how I am making call to my own web api (not ebay api), and that piece of code is completely irrelevant otherwise